# Tittle shows bigger in UITabBarController in iOS 7 programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have implemented UITabBarController programatically. The title of the viewControllers show bigger and clipped. Here is the source code:

```
    var tab: UITabBarController = UITabBarController()
    tab.tabBar.translucent = false

    var homeVC: UINavigationController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as UINavigationController
    homeVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image: UIImage(named: "icon-home"), tag: 0)

    var messagesNavC: UINavigationController = UIStoryboard(name: "Messages", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as UINavigationController
    messagesNavC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Messages", image: UIImage(named: "icon-messages"), tag: 1)

    var quotesRequests: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: UIStoryboard(name: "QuotesRequests", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RSQuoteRequestsViewController") as RSQuoteRequestsViewController) as UINavigationController
    quotesRequests.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Quotes", image: UIImage(named: "icon-quotes"), tag: 2)

    var myAccount: UINavigationController = UIStoryboard(name: "MyAccount", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as UINavigationController
    myAccount.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Account", image: UIImage(named: "icon-account"), tag: 3)

    var helpVC: UINavigationController = UIStoryboard(name: "Help", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as UINavigationController
    helpVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Help", image: UIImage(named: "icon-help"), tag: 4)

    tab.viewControllers = [homeVC, quotesRequests, messagesNavC, myAccount, helpVC]
```

Here is screenshot of how it looks.

[image]
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for altering your size

```
let appearance = UITabBarItem.appearance()
let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "American Typewriter",size: 20)]
appearance.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, forState: .Normal)
```

Or you can try this as well :

```
 [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:20.0f], NSFontAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```